# How to access values and functions inside statenotifier in riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I implemented user authentication with the `statenotifier` in riverpod it works but I don't know how it works in such a manner. I have to create two providers, a `StateNotifierProvider` to read the values and a `Provider` for the same `statenotifier` to access the functions inside the `statenotifier`.

```
final signInStateNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider((ref) => SignInStateNotifier(authentication));

final signInProvider =
    Provider((ref) => ref.watch(signInStateNotifierProvider));
```

**This is my statenotifier class**

```
class SignInStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<AuthFormStates> {
  SignInStateNotifier(this._authFacade) : super(AuthFormStates.initial());

  final SignInAuthFacade _authFacade;

  Future mapEventToState(SignInFormEvents event) async {
    event.map(
      // email changed
      emailChanged: (event) {
        state = state.copyWith(
          emailAddress: EmailAddress(event.email),
          authFailureOrSuccess: none(),
        );
      },
      // password changed
      passwordChanged: (event) {
        state = state.copyWith(
          password: Password(event.password),
          authFailureOrSuccess: none(),
        );
      },
      signInWithEmailAndPasswordPressed: (event) async {
        await _performActionWithEmailAndPassword(
          _authFacade.signInWithEmailAndPassword,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future _performActionWithEmailAndPassword(
    Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> Function({
      @required EmailAddress emailAddress,
      @required Password password,
    })
        action,
  ) async {
    Either<AuthFailure, Unit> result;
    final isEmailValid = state.emailAddress.isValid();
    final isPasswordValid = state.password.isValid();

    if (isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) {
      state = state.copyWith(
        isSubmitting: true,
        authFailureOrSuccess: none(),
      );

      result = await action(
        emailAddress: state.emailAddress,
        password: state.password,
      );

      state = state.copyWith(
        authFailureOrSuccess: some(result),
      );
    }
    state = state.copyWith(
      isSubmitting: false,
      showErrorMessage: true,
      authFailureOrSuccess: optionOf(result),
    );
  }
}
```

**And this is how I access the statenotifier**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ProviderListener<AuthFormStates>(
          provider: signInStateNotifierProvider.state,
          onChange: (context, state) {
            state.authFailureOrSuccess.fold(
              () {},
              (either) => either.fold(
                (failure) {
                  return null;
                },
                (success) => null,
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Consumer(
            builder: (context, watch, child) {
              final providerState = watch(signInProvider);
              final stateNotifierState =
                  watch(signInStateNotifierProvider.state);
              return Form(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) => providerState.mapEventToState(
                            SignInFormEvents.emailChanged(value)),
                        validator: (_) => stateNotifierState
                            .emailAddress.validatedObject
                            .fold(
                                (l) => l.maybeMap(
                                    orElse: () => null,
                                    invalidEmail: (_) => 'Invalid Email'),
                                (_) => null),
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) => providerState.mapEventToState(
                            SignInFormEvents.passwordChanged(value)),
                        validator: (_) =>
                            stateNotifierState.password.validatedObject.fold(
                                (l) => l.maybeMap(
                                    orElse: () => null,
                                    invalidPassword: (_) => 'Invalid Password'),
                                (_) => null),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            providerState.mapEventToState(const SignInFormEvents
                                .signInWithEmailAndPasswordPressed());
                          },
                          child: const Text('Hello World'))
                    ],
                  ));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works fine but I need to know whether this is the right method or am I wrong. Is there any other method to achieve the same thing I am doing? Please give a solution.

And also what I am doing is right, Please tell me how it works in such a manner. I need a clear understanding of how it works.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `signInProvider` is redundant. It does nothing special but only listen to `signInStateNotifierProvider`.

Inside widget **HomePage**, you can actually call the function inside provider without watch the state by using `context.read(provider)` so you can chagne:

```
final providerState = watch(signInProvider);
providerState.mapEventToState(...)
```

to

```
final providerState = context.read(signInStateNotifierProvider);
providerState.mapEventToState(...)
```

or

```
context.read(signInStateNotifierProvider).mapEventToState(...)
```

Also if you pursue the best performance, you don't need to listen to (watch) `signInStateNotifierProvider` when validating the value. (Because you don't rebuild anything in the widget tree, just fetching the data)

```
validator: (_) => context.read(signInStateNotifierProvider).emailAddress.validatedObject...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have corrected my mistake. But can you please explain how it works and why couldn't I just access the functions inside the `statenotifier` by this alone.

`final signInStateNotifierProvider =StateNotifierProvider((ref) => SignInStateNotifier(authentication));`

Comment: Hi~ Do you mean inside the line in your comment? This line is like a initial constructor of a provider. It only concern the construct of itself. `ref` can be use to listen to other provider and rebuild itself. [Riverpod Doc](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/providers),  [context.read](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#contextreadmyprovider)

Comment: My question is why I couldn't just do it with  `final stateNotifierState =
watch(signInStateNotifierProvider.state);` why should I read the `statenotifier` separately in order to access the function inside it.

Comment: In short(my opinion), I think it is because **Availability** and **Performance**. 1.For usage, `watch(provider)` can only be used when building (in Build method), while you can use read anywhere (ex. onPress, onTap). 2. When you only use read, you can avoid unnecessary rebuilding. Otherwise the widget rebuild every time when the state change.